# No variables show up on inspector, first person controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJ ) 1:1 exactly, and when I tried to go and edit the mouse sensitivity variable, no boxes show up in the script component for me to edit the number.

Here is the code that I took from the video:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse  Y")* mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you never read or print a variable, the compiler and JIT Optimisations are free to remove the dead code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. C and C# are very different languages. Please do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: Check if you have compiler errors, if so, fix them, make sure the name of the class matches exactly the name of the file (**Must be** `MouseLook.cs`, not `mouseLook.cs` or something else)

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet, so have to write it as answer:
In this line:

```
float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse  Y")* mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
```

you have a double space between "Mouse" and "Y", code wouldn`t work.

Also, see your console for warnings and errors - while you have it not fixed, changes not applied to scripts. As mentioned in comments, your script must be named exactly as "MouseLook.cs".